# Mesh shading problem with shade smooth

Tags: mesh, objects

I've created a pile of firewood using rigid bodies. However, upon shading it smooth (and turning on auto smooth), the meshes' shading go problematic.

[image]

[image]

I have tried recalculating the normals but that didn't work out. One user suggested separating one object from the mesh and then rejoining it (didn't work).

Does anybody know why this problem occurs? And if there's any ways I can fix this.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the scale and it will work correctly (not sure why it messes up the shading though)

Comment: Looks like that's the answer. So simple! Thank you!